# android app play youtube

Tags: android

i'm trying use the MediaPlayer and videoView class to play youtube videos

but all failed , is that feasible??

i have seem some app can do that , i'm just thinking how to implement .....= =a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to play it on a device or on emulator?

On a device you can use the default YouTube player to implement it. You need to pass a intent from your application along with the URL...Something like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));
```

[Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)