# How to play YouTube video in my Android application?

Tags: android

How do I play YouTube videos in my application? I want to play video by streaming it directly from YouTube without downloading. Also, while playing videos, I want provide menu options. I don't want to play video using default intent. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)

Comment: Its just 2 min work, enable Youtube option from developer console, download youtube player jar file, start using it, Its simple refer this post http://www.feelzdroid.com/2017/01/embed-youtube-video-player-android-app-example.html

Answer (score 62):

This is the btn click event

```
btnvideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hxy8BZGQ5Jo")));
    Log.i("Video", "Video Playing....");

    }
});
```

this type it opened in another page with the youtube where u can show your video

Comment: this one depends on the YouTube aap, otherwise it opens the video in new webView, i want to play the video in VideoView not in webview.. than suggest some way plz.

Comment: `VideoView` requires the absolute URL of the video, which in YouTube's case is probably not available.

Comment: To any copy & pasters, if you're confused as to why this may not work, there should be a space in newIntent. new Intent

Comment: The question goes likes this "I don't want to play video using default intent."

Answer (score 18):

Steps

1. Create a new Activity, for your player(fullscreen) screen with menu options. 
   Run the mediaplayer and UI in different threads.
2. For playing media - In general to play audio/video there is mediaplayer api in android. 
   FILE_PATH is the path of file - may be url(youtube) stream or local file path

   > ```
   >  MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
   >     mp.setDataSource(FILE_PATH);
   >     mp.prepare();
   >     mp.start();
   > ```

Also check: [Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)
have already discussed this in detail.

Comment: how can FILE_PATH point to a youtube video?  A youtube link a web page that plays the video, not a link to the file itself.

Comment: Youtube doesn't have any absolute url. That was the original concern of the OP.

Comment: @MartyMiller Getting stream Url from youtube is different question. It concerns with youtube api's.

Answer (score 16):

Use YouTube Android Player API.

activity_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.andreaskonstantakos.vfy.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
android:text="Button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="195dp"
android:visibility="visible"
android:id="@+id/button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.andreaskonstantakos.vfy;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;



public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
Button button;
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
     button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


     onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener(){

         @Override
         public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("Hce74cEAAaE");

             youTubePlayer.play();
     }

         @Override
         public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

         }
     };

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

youTubePlayerView.initialize(PlayerConfig.API_KEY,onInitializedListener);
        }
    });
}
}
```

and the PlayerConfig.java class:

```
    package com.example.andreaskonstantakos.vfy;

/**
 * Created by Andreas Konstantakos on 13/4/2017.
 */

public class PlayerConfig {

PlayerConfig(){}

public static final String API_KEY = 
"xxxxx";
}
```

Replace the "Hce74cEAAaE" with your video ID from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hce74cEAAaE.
Get your API_KEY from Console.developers.google.com and also replace it on the PlayerConfig.API_KEY.
For any further information you can follow the following tutorial step by step:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LiubyYpEUk

Comment: If I want to use the dynamic video-id then m getting "YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Embed config is not supported in RemoteEmbeddedPlayer." error and its not playing my video. Can u help me out... Thanks in advance.

Comment: youTubePlayerView.initialize doesn't exist, maybe removed?

Answer (score 8):

I didn't want to have to have the YouTube app present on the device so I used this tutorial:

http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/09/how-to-embed-youtube-video-in-android-webview.html

...to produce this code in my app:

```
WebView mWebView; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.video_webview);
    mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    //build your own src link with your video ID
    String videoStr = "<html><body>Promo video<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/47yJ2XCRLZs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadData(videoStr, "text/html", "utf-8");

}

//video_webview
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/bmp_programme_ll"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <WebView
    android:id="@+id/videoview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

This worked just how I wanted it. It doesn't autoplay but the video streams within my app.  Worth noting that some restricted videos won't play when embedded.

Comment: Yes you right embedded with your app with webview without youtube api nice way to load video within app thanks you JanB

Comment: Great easy solution that doesn't require signing up for an API key like [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).  Worked for me!

Comment: Note that the constructor used in this answer for shouldOverrideUrlLoading is now deprecated, and should use this constructor now:

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return false;
            }
        });

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)

Comment: The code snippet should also call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in onCreate

Comment: I would also recommend setting width to 100% instead of 420

Answer (score 3):

Google has a [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) that enables you to incorporate video playback functionality into your Android applications. The API itself is very easy to use and works well. For example, here is how to create a new activity to play a video using the API.

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, "<<YOUTUBE_API_KEY>>", "<<Youtube Video ID>>", 0, true, false);   
startActivity(intent);
```

See [this](http://sapandiwakar.in/streaming-youtube-videos-in-android/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You may use iframe as described in https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

I am not following the google advises exactly but this is the code I am using and it is working fine

```
public class CWebVideoView {

    private String url;
    private Context context;
    private WebView webview;
    private static final String HTML_TEMPLATE = "webvideo.html";

    public CWebVideoView(Context context, WebView webview) {
        this.webview = webview;
        this.context = context;
        webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    public void load(String url){
        this.url = url;
        String data = readFromfile(HTML_TEMPLATE, context);
        data = data.replace("%1", url);
        webview.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }

    public String readFromfile(String fileName, Context context) {
        StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream fIn = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
            fIn = context.getResources().getAssets().open(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
            input = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                returnString.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (isr != null)
                    isr.close();
                if (fIn != null)
                    fIn.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return returnString.toString();
    }

    public void reload() {
        if (url!=null){
            load(url);
        }
    }
}
```

in /assets I have a file called webvideo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            iframe   { border: 0; position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; bgcolor="#000000"; }
            body     { margin: 0; bgcolor="#000000"; }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="%1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

and now I define a webview inside my main layout

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and I use CWebVideoView inside my activity

```
videoView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.video);
videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
cWebVideoView = new CWebVideoView(context, videoView);
cWebVideoView.load(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you put a screenshot so that we can see the result of the code as well?

Answer (score 2):

This answer could be really late, but its useful.

You can play youtube videos in the app itself using [android-youtube-player](https://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/).

**Some code snippets:**

To play a youtube video that has a video id in the url, you simply call the `OpenYouTubePlayerActivity` intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytv://"+v), this, 
            OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

where v is the video id.

Add the following permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

and also declare this activity in the manifest file:

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity"></activity>
```

Further information can be obtained from the first portions of [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/source/browse/trunk/OpenYouTubeActivity/src/com/keyes/youtube/OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.java) code file.

Hope that helps anyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer(); 
mp.setDataSource(path);
mp.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
mp.setDisplay(holder);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5m93hidt35gwu3k/QZcJt6_PQs) project to play any you tube video , in your android app . 
Now for other video , or Video id ... you can do this 
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/eminemvevo/uploads/
where **eminemvevo = channel** .

after finding , video id , you can put that id in `cueVideo("video_id")`

```
src -> com -> examples -> youtubeapidemo -> PlayerViewDemoActivity

  @Override
  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player , boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
      player.cueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
    }
  }
```

And specially for reading that video_id in a better way [open](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/eminemvevo/uploads/) this , and it as a xml[`1st_file`] file in your desktop after it create a new **Xml file** in your `project` or upload that[`1st_file`] saved file in your project , and right_click in it , and open it with xml_editor file , here you will find the video id of the particular video .

[image]

Answer (score -5):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watchv=cxLG2wtE7TM"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Really? "I don't want to play video using default intent.", second to last line.

Comment: This is just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4654937).