# How to play youtube video in my android app?

Tags: android, video, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to play YouTube video in my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)

Im developing a small video streaming app in android but it is not playing **youtube** video so how to play all type of **youtube** video in my application without using `intent` of youtube player.