# Play Video by staying in the same Activity

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have referred the answers of

[android-youtube-app-play-video-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)

[how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)

and many more.All those are playing videos by using `Intent` which creates a new Window and to be more precise by creating a new Activity.

But,I am having a scenario in which I want to play a Video on click of a Button by staying in the same Activity

---

refer this video tutorial:
http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/using-audio-video-files-tutorial-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

Use a VideoView
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: I think he is asking about playing videos from youtube. Not the normal way of playing videos.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play a video file from phone storage or streaming, you can use [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html).

If you want to open youtube video, you can use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in your activity and open the youtube link.
See this [WebView Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html).