# YouTube: Play On Android Application

Tags: android, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to play YouTube video in my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)

How can i play a youtube video in my android Application. There are so many person gives there view but its not working. Can anyone provide me any solution.

I am facing getting exception:

```
07-20 14:32:50.898: E/MediaPlayer(4130): error (1, -2147483648)
```

07-20 14:32:50.914: E/MediaPlayerDemo(4130): error: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
07-20 14:32:50.914: E/MediaPlayerDemo(4130): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
07-20 14:32:50.914: E/MediaPlayerDemo(4130):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-20 14:32:50.914: E/MediaPlayerDemo(4130):    at com.youtube.MainMenu.playVideo(MainMenu.java:133)
07-20 14:32:50.914: E/MediaPlayerDemo(4130):    at com.youtube.MainMenu.surfaceCreated(MainMenu.java:188)

Comment: What kind of youtube videos you want to play? Direct streaming, or playing any youtube URL.

Comment: playing youtube url in my application

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309821/1441666

And also

```
    video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://v6.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQk-fYZWNAPDsxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"));
    mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(video);
    video.start();
```

Comment: As you are getting proper path of you tube video but i am unable to get that