# How to play Youtube videos in Android apps?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I want to know all ways to play video without go to youtube aplication ?

what's the fastest way?

what the advantage or disadvantages if i used yotube-API or in webview

Answer (score 1):

You can use [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) or [YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) to play a video within your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following for streaming your YouTube if you'd like.

[YouTube streaming within Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)

Essentially, all you need to do is load an built-in Activity or present the video in a webview embedded inside your application where you would want it.