# Android Studio: Insert a YouTube channel feed into my app?

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, youtube-api

So I want to put a tab into my app that shows a feed of the latest videos from a YouTube channel. The tab is already there, just need to discover how to put the videos. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play YouTube video in my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

You require the ID of the uploads playlist from the user

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it

Do a http GET request like this

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=jambrose42&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

You can specify the username with the forUsername={username} param, or specify mine=true to get your own (you need to authenticate first). Include part=contentDetails to see the playlists.

In the result. Grab that "upload" playlist ID.

Next, get a list of videos in that playlist:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUpRmvjdu3ixew5ahydZ67uA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

For Reference -

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#try-it

Comment: Thanks. Now that I have that list of videos? How would I put them into Android Studio?

Comment: You parse the relevant information you want and then inject them in to your views, lets say - you have a recyclerview/listview and each item has the view name and the imageview for the thumbnail - you just iterate through the api response and keep injecting the relevant information in each listview item