# How to play webview YouTube link in YouTube API?

Tags: java, android

First activity of my app has a webview with some YouTube videos links. I want to know is this possible if user clicking on video link in webview, app can play that video in second activity with YouTube Android library.

Answer (score 0):

Providing some code snippets could help. 
Override your webClient's `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` method.

There you can get the url thats about to be loaded using `request.getUrl()` and check it's a valid Youtube Url. Showing the youtube video depends on the availability of the youtube app.

Check the [Youtube docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) and this [SOF question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)