embeded youtube video won't start in webview - android
I'm trying to play a youtube video, that embeded in the page into some custom video player, in webview based app (it's not a youtube url, but a site with the video embeded in it). I can see the video thumbnail, but when I pressing on the video, it's not starting. It's seems like the video is about to start, when the thumnail changes to blank, but then it's stops and the thumbnail returns.
Also getting this in the logcat:

[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to
load because no supported source was found.", source:
https://www.niby.org.il/lessons/%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%90%d7%96%d7%9b%d7%a8%d7%94-%d7%9c%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%a6%d7%91%d7%99-%d7%99%d7%94%d7%95%d7%93%d7%94-%d7%96%d7%a6%d7%9c-%d7%94%d7%aa%d7%a9%d7%a4%d7%93/
(0)

My manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AlHatora"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.niby.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="niby.org.il" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="*.niby.org.il" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="niby.org.il" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="*.niby.org.il" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

The activity:
package com.app.niby;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdvancedWebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        costumwebviewclient client = new costumwebviewclient(this);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());
        webView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setMixedContentAllowed(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url){
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("niby.org.il")){
                    // This is my web site, so do not override; let the WebView load the page.
                    return false;
                }
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("googleapis.com")){
                    // This is my web site, so do not override; let the WebView load the page.
                    return false;
                }
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("youtube.com")){
                    // This is my web site, so do not override; let the WebView load the page.
                    return false;
                }
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("w3.org")){
                    // This is my web site, so do not override; let the WebView load the page.
                    return false;
                }

                // Reject everything else.
                return true;
            }
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request){
                if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("niby.org.il")) {
                    //The current WebView handles the url.
                    return false;

                }
                if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("googleapis.com")) {
                    //The current WebView handles the url.
                    return false;

                }
                if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("youtube.com")) {
                    //The current WebView handles the url.
                    return false;

                }
                if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("w3.org")) {
                    //The current WebView handles the url.
                    return false;

                }

                // Reject everything else.
                return true;
            }


        });
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if(data != null) {
            //Load the deep-link url:
            String url = intent.getDataString();
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
        else
        {
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.niby.org.il/");
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(
                    WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
        }

        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );




    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && this.webView.canGoBack()){
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {
        View fullscreen = null;

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView()
        {
            fullscreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback)
        {
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if(fullscreen != null)
            {
                ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(fullscreen);
            }

            fullscreen = view;
            ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(fullscreen, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
            fullscreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

class  costumwebviewclient extends WebViewClient{
    private Activity activity;

    public costumwebviewclient(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    //api level less than 24
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url){
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("niby.org.il")){
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let the WebView load the page.
        return false;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("googleapis.com")){
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let the WebView load the page.
            return false;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("youtube.com")){
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let the WebView load the page.
            return false;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("w3.org")){
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let the WebView load the page.
            return false;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("google.com")){
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let the WebView load the page.
            return false;
        }

        // Reject everything else.
        return true;
    }

    //api level >=24
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request){
        if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("niby.org.il")) {
            //The current WebView handles the url.
            return false;

        }
        if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("googleapis.com")) {
            //The current WebView handles the url.
            return false;

        }
        if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("youtube.com")) {
            //The current WebView handles the url.
            return false;

        }
        if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("w3.org")) {
            //The current WebView handles the url.
            return false;

        }
        if(Uri.parse(request.getUrl().toString()).getHost().endsWith("google.com")) {
            //The current WebView handles the url.
            return false;

        }

        // Reject everything else.
        return true;
    }

   }

my layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.niby.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageLoading1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/images"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageLoading2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="160.5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="160.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cc"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

sorry for my poor english, thanks.
Tried this: how to solve problem webview to play audio , but not working for me.

In my opinion, it might be useful to consult JanB's answer [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application) which I used for my app

thank you for the comment, but I don't have a specific youtube url, but a site with lot of videos from youtube, and the videos won't start.

Have you also tried setting     WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

yes I added it, but not working.

it seems like it something with [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found."

I tried your site in my app's test environment and it works (the audio starts) for me putting :
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Consult Jacks answer [link] (Allow navigation in Android webview)

thank you, but it's already added in my activity. and what do you mean that the audio starts, from the video?

i added my project to github: link

Dear Lior, unfortunately I don't have the time to examine your project. I tried again with the test environment of my app and in fact clicking on the play buttons on the first page of the site the audio starts, but clicking on the video pages on logcat reports the error "Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found., source: https://www.niby.org.il/lessons/%d7%a1%.."

Since the site uses WP Rocket, in my opinion, one way to try could be the WordPress API
