Can we open a Youtube live streaming link from Android app if we have the link? If yes then please explain how?
Can we open a YouTube live streaming link from the Android app if we have the link?
If yes then please explain how?
Or
Let's say I have the live-streaming link, can I open the Youtube app and go directly to that live video either in my own android app in a web view or in YouTube app.

Use webview in your own app.

This is the code used in my app
    /**
 * <h1>YoutubePrizeFragment</h1>
 *
 * **YoutubePrizeFragment** UI for prize
 * upload a Youtube video as a reward
 *
 * Refer to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)
 * answer of [JanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957925/janb)
 *
 * @version     5.0, 01/04/2024
 */
class YoutubePrizeFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var rootView: View
    var textView: TextView? = null
    lateinit var ctext: Context

    //
    var mWebView: WebView? = null
    val videoStr1 = "<html><body>Promo video from <br>"
    val videoStr2Portrait =
        "<iframe width=\"426\" height=\"240\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
    val videoStr2Landscape =
        "<iframe width=\"213\" height=\"120\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
    val videoStr3 = "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
    val wwwUrlSplitBy = "v="
    val androidUrlSplitBy = "be/"

    //
    lateinit var listener: onFragmentEventListenerYoutubePrize

    /**
     * <h1>onFragmentEventListenerYoutubePrize</h1>
     *
     * **onFragmentEventListenerYoutubePrize**
     * interface used to refer to the Activity without having to explicitly use its class
     *
     *
     *
     * @see onAttach
     */
    interface onFragmentEventListenerYoutubePrize {
        // insert here any references to the Activity
        fun receiveResultImagesFromYoutubePrizeFragment(v: View?)
        fun receiveResultOnCompletatioVideoFromYoutubePrizeFragment(v: View?)
    }

    /**
     * listener setting for game activities callbacks , context annotation
     *
     * @see Fragment.onAttach
     */
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        val activity = context as Activity
        listener = activity as onFragmentEventListenerYoutubePrize
        //
        ctext = context
    }

    /**
     * prepares the ui and makes the callback to the activity
     *
     *
     *
     * @see Fragment.onCreateView
     *
     * @see WebViewClient
     */
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_game_prize_youtube, container, false)
        //
        mWebView = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.youtubevideoview) as WebView
        //
        val bundle = this.arguments
        var uriPremiumVideo: String? = ""
        if (bundle != null) {
            uriPremiumVideo = bundle.getString(getString(R.string.uri_premium_video))
        }
        //
        if (!uriPremiumVideo!!.uppercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(
                wwwUrlSplitBy.uppercase(
                    Locale.getDefault()
                )
            ) &&
            !uriPremiumVideo.uppercase(Locale.getDefault())
                .contains(androidUrlSplitBy.uppercase(Locale.getDefault()))
        ) {
            // if the video award does not exist, it warns the activity that the award
            // has been completed and therefore you can continue
            mWebView!!.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            //
            listener.receiveResultOnCompletatioVideoFromYoutubePrizeFragment(rootView)
        } else {
            // build your own src link with your video ID
            val oneWord: Array<String?>
            oneWord = if (uriPremiumVideo.uppercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(
                    wwwUrlSplitBy.uppercase(
                        Locale.getDefault()
                    )
                )
            ) {
                uriPremiumVideo.split(wwwUrlSplitBy).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
            } else {
                uriPremiumVideo.split(androidUrlSplitBy).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }
                    .toTypedArray()
            }
            // builds the src link (including size and address)
            // The Right YouTube Dimensions = 426X240
            val orientation = this.resources.configuration.orientation
            val videoStr: String
            videoStr = if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                // code for portrait mode
                videoStr1 + uriPremiumVideo + videoStr2Portrait + oneWord[1] + videoStr3
            } else {
                // code for landscape mode
                videoStr1 + uriPremiumVideo + videoStr2Landscape + oneWord[1] + videoStr3
            }
            //
            mWebView!!.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView,
                    request: WebResourceRequest
                ): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    val TIME_OUT = 180000
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                        listener.receiveResultOnCompletatioVideoFromYoutubePrizeFragment(
                            rootView
                        )
                                                                }, TIME_OUT.toLong())
                }
            }
            val ws = mWebView!!.settings
            ws.javaScriptEnabled = true
            mWebView!!.loadData(videoStr, "text/html", "utf-8")
        }
        listener.receiveResultImagesFromYoutubePrizeFragment(rootView)
        return rootView
    }

    /**
     * destroy WebView
     *
     *
     *
     * @see Fragment.onDestroyView
     */
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        mWebView!!.destroy()
        mWebView = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}    

