# You tube video not playing

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview, viewstub

I am trying to call you tube from my web view which is associated with a view stub. The problem is I am able to load the you tube but if I click on the play button of you tube, it is not playing

Here is what I am trying to do

webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

WebSettings webSet = webView.getSettings();

webSet.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// setContentView(webView);

webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaIPQMVMRqU&feature=related");

Comment: is your android phone support flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included a transparent button on the web view and finally I am able to play it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
[Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)

Apparently on emulator this doesn't work but on device it works. Were you running it only on the emulator?

Your code should work, try it on a real device.

You should better use the url you get in share section of youtube than the one you use: http://youtu.be/QaIPQMVMRqU

Comment: I am running on the device only.

Comment: is there an interesting thing in logcat?

Comment: when browsing youtube site from the webexplorer, does playing the video works?

Comment: yeah in that case it works, no i din't find anything special in log cat.

Comment: I tried it on my device it works fine. Can't help you much more.. =(

Comment: yeah now it is working for me also,one doubt I have at this point. Is it possible to call a onClicklistener for webview. If so does it work fine? Because I have implemented a click listener for my webview object but it is not happening..

Comment: It's not an onclicklistener but an ontouchlistener.

Answer (score 0):

if you have made it in android 2.1 that code will not be able to play video on emulator ,
buti f you intall that same on a android device version 2.2 it will work

if you want to play it in emulator just make it on android version 2.2