# Android - Open YouTube video via Link in TextView

Tags: java, android, youtube

I have an app that I wish to put links in that will open the youtube player, the link will be located within a text view.

Can anyone help me achieve this as simply using Link text does not work ??

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess this is what you're looking for: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/auto-link-for-textview/

Cheers,

Pete Houston