# Play a YouTube video embedded in a url in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a url which i am displaying in the webview, it coutains embedded youtube video and but i am unable to play the video, i have looked into many posts but none of them seems to help. Can you suggest me some ideas for the workaround of this problem ...

Thanks...

Comment: The embedded player at least works in a WebView on Ice Cream Sandwich, provided it is the new embed code that adapts to flash or html5. However, at least on the tablets we are using to test, a strip of the video on the right side is lost when playback starts.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a more generic intent [to view a video through another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent). Webviews are somewhat limited and depend a lot on platform abilities. If you used a third party app, like youtube, your app would then benefit of

- a video player choosen by the user himself according to is/her taste
- an up-to-date video player, more independant of android native capabilities
- one less problem to solve. :)

Comment: What if i dont have the youtube url, the youtube video is embedded in another html page... ??

Comment: extract it using a regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following intent

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8EKth4TTrM")));
```

Comment: problem is that i dont have the youtube url, it is embedded in another html page...

Comment: for that you have to open that html page in webview or parse your html to extract youtube Url

Comment: You may try to extract the youtube URL from the html.

Comment: what if i dont want it to open in a ACTION_VIEW intent not a brower but in my webview only ... ??

Comment: @King: As far as i know, it is not possible to play YouTube video URL's directly in a WebView.