# YouTube link on WebView do not open Youtube

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I have been working on an appliction, the requirement states that i need to open a Youtube link on the web view. Once clicked on the video i need to open the Youtube application to play the video.

After lots of try had not been quite successful to achieve this goal!
Looking forward for sugestions.

this is what i tried.

```
        wb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.setWebViewClient(new MyClient());
        wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        wb.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        wb.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        wb.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com");


private class MyClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(!pgd.isShowing()){
                        pgd.show();
                    }
                }
            });
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i("url loaded", "url::: " + url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(pgd !=null && pgd.isShowing()){
                        pgd.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }
```

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can get some idea from this [post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this problem? I am facing this too :(

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have the URL of video and also have youtube's application installed on android device, I have better idea.

Use `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("url of youtube video")));`

This will pop up user and will display option of browser and YouTube, and if YouTube is selected the video will be played in YouTube player.

Comment: :) requirement says it otherwise.. i too sugested... but client is client :D

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and got the solution by adding this line:

```
wb.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
```

Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried this already.. yes it works too but the web page is of the Desktop not for mobile.. hence it looks quite odd... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this in onCreate():

```
    WebView webview = new WebView(this); 

   String htmlString = "<html> <body> <embed src=\"link of youtube video\"; type=application/x-shockwave-flash width="+DeviceWidth+" height="+DeviceHeight+"> </embed> </body> </html>";

   webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlString ,"text/html", "UTF-8",null);
   webview.setWebViewClient(new MyClient());
```

Comment: cannot put in embed as i am suppose to show channel not only a video :(
anyways thanks for sugestion..

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the WebChromeClient and set it as the client of the webview. Then handle the video playback in the onShowCustomView callback.