# Best option to access youtube videos in android application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)

I am going to implement the application which access the youtube video. Am new to android and kindly give me some links of sample programs related to my application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ACTION_VIEW` intent
`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<something>")));`

[This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/youtube_mobileresources) page has more details