# Buffer youtube video in Android app

Tags: android, youtube

Followed stackoverflow discussion [Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent?answertab=active#tab-top)

I tried this code but it didn't work

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));
```

I got this error  in console but no output in logcat:

```
[2012-11-20 17:49:21 - Youtube] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2012-11-20 17:49:21 - Youtube] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-11-20 17:49:22 - Youtube] Launch canceled!
```

Logcat doesn't have any error record.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334252/1627599)

There is a slight suggestive change in the code that you have posted

Comment: that is the first part of the uri after which you have to supply the video id

Comment: btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    String videoId = "rNBptkh5NHg&feature=g-all-u";
    Intent intent = new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
      Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
        + videoId));
    intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
  });

This is my code. on button click a blank page opens. I have internet    permissions in manifest. wats d problem then? plz suggest

Comment: Somebody please post a working version of youtube video in android. I need it urgently.