# Youtube Playlist using Intent without showing dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

In my program i am **launching Youtube Playlist**, but it ***always showing dialog to choose the way to open***, options like:- Browser, Youtube etc.

may i know if i directly want to call using Youtube, without showing any dialog, so what i need to use, see my code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent

Comment: @EugenMartynov that's not duplicate, here i want to know how to launch Playlist not the single youtube video

Comment: kind of agree, but there are tons answers for that question and some of them give you idea how to make it working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's check it once, i believe this will resolve your issue, just copy and paste my code:

```
    Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

and let me know if you have any query ? ok !

Comment: yeah you should Proud to be a Google APIs Professional +1

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following code.

This code will directly start the default Youtube app to play the youtube video.

```
String videoId = "youryoutubevideoid";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+videoId)); 
intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId); 
startActivity(intent);
```

EDIT :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=" + playlist_id);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(uri);
    i.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube", "com.google.android.youtube.app.froyo.phone.PlaylistActivity");
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: but he is directly passing playlist URL to play in sequence

Comment: i am not trying to play single video

Comment: Be careful since Youtube application is not bundled in stock Android

Comment: @Prince what about this line: com.google.android.youtube.app.froyo.phone.PlaylistActivity    i am using gingerbread or above

Comment: @PatharKeSanam Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13826023/1405983 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489306/intent-to-play-youtube-playlist

Comment: i earlier tried this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489306/intent-to-play-youtube-playlist but getting :: YouTubeIntents cannot be resolved

Comment: You can also check : https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents

Answer (score 0):

The Video Can be played in two different ways:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + id));
startActivity(intent);
```

The id is the identifier after the questionmark in the url. For example: **"youtube.com/watch?v=ID"**

Another way is:

```
String url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxx";
    Intent videoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    videoIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    videoIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube", "com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity");
    startActivity(videoIntent);
```

Comment: The method setData(Uri) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)    using this: videoIntent.setData("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A");

Comment: not done, able to launch youtube, but not getting Playlist, i guess problem in this line: "com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity"