# on clicking button how can we play a video on youtube?

Tags: android, youtube

I am working on an app in which I have a button that I want to onClick redirect to a link of youtube, means on clicking that button youtube should open and video should be played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intenting Inbuilt YouTube App**

Make an intent that resolves to a `youtube URL`. If the **youtube app is installed, it will ask if you want to open in youtube.**

Or 
you can use a youtube-explicit intent, but if the app isn't installed it will cause an error.

[Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)