# Using ACTION_VIEW will pop up chooser dialog twice when url is google play

Tags: android

all
I'm very confused with this scenario.
I need to open a link using default android browser in my app.
The link is Google Play.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://play.google.com"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The reason I don't use market:// is because some regions will not have Google Play apk.

It pops up a chooser dialog includes Chrome , Play Store , Browser.
After I choose Browser, default browser does launch but it pops up chooser again.
Even I choose Chrome, both will have the same action.

If I use `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com"));`

It only pop up once and show yahoo homepage correctly.
I tried under Android 4.0.4 and 4.2

Is it correct scenario?
How can I avoid it pop up twice?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is happening to me also with the address: `http://m.youtube.com/home`. Did you resolve? Thanks

Comment: @dentex you can explicitly set youtube class name. See this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6781064/1005846

Comment: @elf_zwölf Well, I actually wanted to show the website, not the app. Anyway, I resolved inserting a **#**, like this: **http://m.youtube.com/#/home**. This is into the address bar after the second chooser and after a redirection. Putting directly this works well in my case.

Comment: @dentex , cool, due to my project was done, I'm not sure if it works for mine.Anyway, thanks for your sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a correct scenario. The first pop-up because your app asks Android what app should be used, then your browser asks android should the link be opened by itself or use special application

Comment: Thanks for your explanation,guy.It seems no one else has other explanation.

Comment: second popup actually shows with the stock browser. Not happening with Firefox. tested on two emulators (4.3 and 4.4.2) and a device (4.3.1).