# How play Youtube video from default application

Tags: android, youtube

I am using this code to load Youtube video by launching an intent to let the user choose what video application to use:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watchv=cxLG2wtE7TM")));
```

By doing this I am able to load the Youtube webpage and user need to click play button to play the  video, then video starts to play. How can I avoid this intermediate step.

Comment: you want the video get played without pressing the play button ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post maybe [Android YouTube app Play Video Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)

And here is the official documentation :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary