# How to Play Youtube Playlist Intent Videos in Full Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api

I am beginner in android and developing an app in which i am using YouTubePlayer API in order to show Youtube Videos of specific Playlist. I'm succeed in doing so. But what I want is that whenever the user selects any video from that playlist; the video should be played in Full Screen. Here is my code:

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Toolbar main_toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
        main_toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_thirdtoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(main_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.my_tb_title);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.tblogo);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }

    public void OnClickButtonListener()
    {
        Button youtubebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        youtubebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String PLAYLIST_ID = "PLXRActLQ03oY_6AQb-5EMuKFYQA_fDE40";
                Intent intent=YouTubeIntents.createOpenPlaylistIntent(Main4Activity.this,PLAYLIST_ID);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods from [**YouTubeIntents**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents). Here are some methods that you can use:

- [`canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions (Context context)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions(android.content.Context))

  Checks if the YouTube application installed on the user's device supports the `fullscreen` and `finishOnEnd` optional parameters when resolving a play video intent.

  - If this method returns `true`, then your application can call the `createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(Context context, String videoId, boolean fullscreen, boolean finishOnEnd)` method which creates an Intent that, when resolved, will start playing the video specified by `videoId`, within the YouTube application.
  - If this method returns `false`, then your application should call the `createPlayVideoIntent(Context context, String videoId)` method instead.

Additionally, please also check other implementations and try the suggested solutions in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent). Hope it helps!

Comment: I have used createPlayVideoIntent method. and it shows the playlist but i want that when user clicks on any video from that playlist it will be played in full screen

Comment: Have you also used `canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions()` method?

Comment: I had posted the code above. i have only used one method to show specific playlist videos.

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation that I have given, use the `canResolve` methods before sending an intent to make sure that the user's device has a version of the YouTube application that supports the given intent.