# Open youtube video at a specific time using android intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am opening a youtube video from my app, similar with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12439378/379865

I was wondering if it's possible to open the video at a specified time, so for instance have video running from 30 seconds at start, not from the beginning.

Comment: I think when you share Youtube videos at a specific time the link changes, so you might need to change the link to the video accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

YouTube have a great way of indicating time in their URL for the videos.

- So let's say a `url` of a video is
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z149x12sXsw
- You can reference the same URL with it playing automatically 30
  seconds in by putting `&t=0m30s` at the end.
- When you open the video, pass in the new `url` with the new
  extension. It should look something like
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z149x12sXsw&t=0m30s

The `Intent` will look something like `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z149x12sXs" + time)));` where `String time = "&t=0m30s";`

**Edit**: Expansion for YouTube App.

```
public static void watchYoutubeVideo(String id, String time){
    Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id + time));
    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id + time));
    try {
        startActivity(appIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        startActivity(webIntent);
    }
}
```

Using another answer from that question. The same logic can be applied to any intent just add the `Time` string to the `URI` like shown above regardless of intention.

Comment: This works when starting the video in a browser. I need to test when using the YT app. Thanks

Comment: For me, by using `vnd.youtube` way on android 5 does not work. It opens the youtube app but fails to load the video. However, opening with webIntent works, even if selection from menu to open with YouTube app.

Answer (score 0):

Try Opening url with url something similar to this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0IU8uQniX8&t=2m35s

where t= time in minutes and seconds

`t=2m35s`