# How to make an Implicit Intent so that it opens a specific video in the youtube app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, youtube

Basically I am making a simple app and I need to know that how when you click a button a video in the youtube app opens up and can be watched. I could not find any code that I could understand. Thank You your help it will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho I have downvoted Ill give you an answer from a single google search.

Just a simple line of code: `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));`

It won't work on the emulator, only on your phone. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)