# How to connect alarm clock app with you tube?

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want create in java alarm clock app and when alarm it's turned on I want connect to video (specific url) on you tube (video must be start automatically). How I can do it at all or it's impossible?

Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible - you can use an `AlarmManager` to set an alarm, and when it's triggered open `YouTube` with an `Intent` (assuming the app is installed on the user's phone) [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try - it's untested, but should launch a YouTube video using whatever browser is installed on a user's device.

```
public static void setYouTubeAlarm(String videoId, long alarmTime) {
    final Intent launchYoutube = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoId));
    final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchYouTube, 0);
    final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help :) After entering this code I will let you know how it went;)